# VB.Net code to unzip password protected file

Tags: vb.net

Below code I am using for unzip a zip file from one folder to another. But I need code two unzip password protected file. Also I need code to unzip multiple zip file from a folder at a time (One by one using loop).

```
    Dim startPath As String = "E:\Asp.net\CC_Folders"
    Dim zipPath As String = "E:\Asp.net\CC_Folder\Sci-hub.rar"
    Dim extractPath As String = "E:\Asp.net\CC_Extract"

    'ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)
    'ZipFile.pass

    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
```

Comment: look for sharpziplib  https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/help/api/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.html

Answer (score 0):

I use Ionic.Zip

Extract , add etc

https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/VB.htm

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Using zip As New ZipFile()
        zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256
        zip.Password = "123456789"
        zip.AddFile("H:Test\Floris.txt")
       
        zip.Save("H:Test\EncryptedArchive.dll")
    End Using
End Sub



Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    ' Extract a zip archive that uses AES Encryption.
    ' You do not need to specify the algorithm during extraction.
    Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read("H:Test\EncryptedArchive.dll")
        zip.Password = "123456789"
        zip.ExtractAll("H:Test22")
    End Using

End Sub

Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Try
        Using zip As New ZipFile()
            zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256
            zip.Password = "123456789"
            zip.AddDirectory("H:\Test")
            zip.Save("H:\Test\Encrypt.zip")
            MsgBox("Files zipped")
        End Using
    Catch ex As ZipException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Try
        Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read("H:\Test\Encrypt.zip")
            zip.Password = "123456789"
            zip.ExtractAll("H:Test2")
            MsgBox("Files unzipped")
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
  
End Sub
```

End Class